# Additive or multiplicative decomposing?

Tags: macroeconomics, r

I am going to decompose one of my time series. My goal is to get rid of the seasonal component. It looks like this:

[image: Timeseries]
[image: Log]

The last picture is: log(next value/present value)

I have understood that if the seasonal variation is constant, you should use an additive model. And if the time series increases in magnitude, you should use an multiplicative model.

The graph is measuring income.

In my case it looks like there is a bit of both, so I can't figure out which one to use. Would anybody please help?

Thanks